# ROS rgbdslam fuerte support?

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd6dslam, rgbd, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know when will there be support for [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) in fuerte. I tried to tinker with the electric supported version to make it run in fuerte but could not get it to work. If someone has found a way around please let me know.

The errors are listed below:

- rosdep was nable to find eigen(resolved),gl2ps,qt4,libglew,libdevil.
- src files in g2o do not seem to automatically resolve header files( I had to change many paths to make these error go)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40059/ros-rgbdslam-fuerte-support???/) by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2012-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-07-31**:
exactly what problem do you have while running it? Not able to built the package successfully

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-01**:
check below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

follow this:

1. 1st built ros package g2o in the proper ros package path. don't make any change in paths. Nothing you have to edit in g2o.
2. next edit manifest.xml in rgbdslam package. delete the line '' and add the following

then you can find something similar to loop starting and ending with . within that add the following line without editing other lines:

3.then install qt4. simply, use ubuntu software centre. In devoloper tools -> IDE. you can find it (most probably in the name qt creator).

4.then

$ sudo apt-get install libglew1.5-dev libdevil-dev libsuitesparse-dev

$ sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev

5.then do $ rosmake rgbdslam. Incase, if you find any error try it with $ rosmake --pre-clean rgbdslam.

I hope it should work.

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2